# How would I use a while loop?

Tags: c++

> ask how many expenses they have for the month. Loop (using a for-loop) for each of these expenses, asking how much they spent on each one. Numbering for expenses should display for the user starting at one. Keep a running track of how much they're spending as you're looping.
>
> For each expense, verify that the expense costs at least $0.01 in a loop (using a while-loop).
>
> They shouldn't be able to move on until they've entered in a valid expense.

Here is the code shown below. when I input 0 just to see if the while loop works, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
int main()
{ 
    // Variables // 
    double monthlyIncome, monthlySave, monthlyBudget, ex_cost = 0.01, ex_num;
    int expenseMonth;

    // A warm welcome message//
    cout << "Welcome to the budget calculator" << endl;

    // user puts in monthly income and how much they would like to save//
    cout << "Please enter your starting monthly income: ";
    cin >> monthlyIncome;
    cout << "Please enter how much you would like to save: ";
    cin >> monthlySave; 

    //Calculating and outputting  monthly budget//
    monthlyBudget = monthlyIncome - monthlySave;
    cout << "Your monthly budget is: $" << monthlyBudget << endl;

    // user inputs expense number //
    cout << "How many expenses did you have this month: ";
    cin >> expenseMonth;

    // loop for expenses //
    for (int i = 1; i <= expenseMonth; ++i) {
        cout << "How much did you spend on expense " << i << ":" <<endl;
        cin >> ex_num;
        while (ex_num <= 0.01) {
            cout << "you must have spent at least 0.01 for it to be an expense!" << "Please try again" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a homework or assignment question?

Comment: its an assignment question. I was just stuck on my while loop. new to c++ and still trying to learn.

Comment: *"when I input 0 just to see if the while loop works,"* -- testing is good. Even better would be to reduce your **example** code to just this part. Skip everything from "A warm welcome message" to "How much did you spend on expense". As part of this, don't "loop for expenses" -- you are looking at the behavior for a single expense, so you do not need to loop. See also [mre] -- a short demonstration is preferable to a full attempt at your homework assignment.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* -- this explanation is not good. In fact, it is useless. *How* does it not work? What did you expect would happen? What actually happened? Did the loop have zero iterations when you expected some? More iterations than you expected? Did your loop cause your home to teleport across the street? (If you consider that to be "working", then I have seriously misunderstood the intent of the code. :) Point is that outlandish outcomes fall under the description "doesn't work", which is why that description is useless.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop is checking the same expense value over and over without giving the user a chance to change the value if it is not valid, thus it gets stuck in an endless loop.

Also, you are not allowing expenses to be at least `0.01` like the instructions ask for.

Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= expenseMonth; ++i) {
    cout << "How much did you spend on expense " << i << ":" <<endl;
    cin >> ex_num;
    while (ex_num < 0.01) { // <-- needs to be < not <= !
        cout << "you must have spent at least 0.01 for it to be an expense! Please try again" << endl;
        cin >> ex_num; // <-- add this!
    }
}
```

Personally, I would use a `do..while` loop instead, since the input has to be read in at least 1 time, eg:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= expenseMonth; ++i) {
    do {
        cout << "How much did you spend on expense " << i << ":" <<endl;
        cin >> ex_num;
        if (ex_num >= 0.01) break;
        cout << "you must have spent at least 0.01 for it to be an expense! Please try again" << endl;
    }
    while (true);
}
```